# move value from one html form to another, so one form submits values from itself and another form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have 2 html forms, formA and formB. I want to submit both A's and B's values when B is submitted. Here is the code I tried:

```
<script>
function combine()
{
formB=document.getElementById('formB').elements;
formA=document.getElementById('formA').elements;
formB[2]=formA[0];
return true;
}
</script>

<form name=A id=formA>
mydrink: <input type=text value=beer name=mydrink><br>
</form>

<br>

<form name=B id=formB action=forms.html method=get>
bar: <input type=text name=bar value=doogans><br>
<input type=submit onclick="return combine();" value=okie>
</form>
```

The behavior I want is so that when form B is submitted, it posts the values for bar and mydrink, so the resulting url is

```
forms.html?bar=doogans&mydrink=beer
```

but instead I just get

```
forms.html?bar=doogans
```

The code looks like it should work, but clearly does not. Do you know what I am doing wrong or forgetting to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're exploring [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/), here's how you can pull all the `formA` elements when `formB` is submitted.

***HTML***

```
<form name=A id=formA>
    mydrink: <input type=text value=beer name=mydrink /><br />
</form>
<br />
<form name=B id=formB action=forms.html method=get>
    bar: <input type=text name=bar value=doogans /><br />
    <input type=submit value=okie />
</form>
```

***jQuery***

```
$(function() {
    $( '#formB input[type = "submit"]' ).on( 'click', function( e ) {
        $.each( $( '#formA' ).prop( 'elements' ), function( idx, elem ) {
            $( '#formB' ).append( $( '<input />' ).attr({
                type : "hidden",
                name : elem.name,
                value : elem.value
            }));
        });
    });
});
```

Working Demo: **[JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/2LUvh/)** *(Hover on the toolbar in the iframe to see query params after submit)*

Comment: I had half an idea about appending the elements, but sometimes they dont have the most up to date values of input elements. using prop solves that. Perfect solution, thanks.

Comment: @SethCohen Glad to help. +1 to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend two things.

1. Combine the forms into a single form (form tag doesn't really affect styling all that much unless you put dependent CSS on it, which you should be able to replace with a div in that case)
2. Write your own submit handler (jQuery is nice for this). Basically just instead of using forms, use JS/jQuery to write a click handler for a button that pulls values from inputs and submits them.

If you aren't sure how to do that, I could show you if you post all your code.

EDIT:

This is done with jQuery, so make sure you include the jQuery source file in your header.
I'll be using inputs with ID tags id1, id2, id3 and a button with ID tag submit_button for the example.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#submit_button").click( function() {
        var val1 = $("#id1").val();
        var val2 = $("#id2").val();
        var val3 = $("#id3").val();

        var http_str = jQuery.param({ var1: val1, var2: val2, var3: val3});

        window.location = "myscript.php?" + http_str;
    }

});
```

Documentation for this:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: 1. I cannot combine the forms. The example I posted was for simplicity. The forms are being generated by php in different parts of the page. 2. How? That sounds good!

Comment: Also using something like serialize is no go because I want to submit post not get.

Comment: Also, you could still combine forms. Just have the first php generator output only the opening tag and the second php generator output the closing tag.

Comment: Can't combine. the opening must be generated below. Can your code be used to submit as post?

Comment: IF you wanted to do post, it would be easier to write a hidden form and submit it with variables assigned by jQuery.

Comment: But you should be fine with get unless you're submitting sensitive data or massive amounts of data. Just change the variable in your php

Comment: thanks for your help. I had to go with Ravi's solution since it works for POST. For the record, I actually need it to post for a completely different reason: when the the user navigates back to a page from their browser history, I don't want them to navigate to a prepopulated get query string and inadvertently resubmit data. that is why post is essential for me even though the amount of data is small and it is not particularly sensitive.